# Overlay raster (h5 files) with shape files to get night light data in R

Tags: raster, shapefile, r, clip, night-time-images

I am trying to combine ".h5" nightlight data files of Hawaii with zipcode-shapefile from Hawaii, but I am getting the following error:

```
#Error: [crop] extents do not overlap
```

The R codes are below, and the data can be downloaded from the google drive with the link below. https://drive.google.com/drive/u/2/folders/1IpkbgITblqxU9sArUFtD_-Oo3WtF6wQg

Note: If you prefer to use the the official link for data (link below), you need to register.

```
library(terra) # the latest version of raster
library(sf)
# get hc files for jan 1 2022 of hawaii from the link below (need to register for getting data):
# https://ladsweb.modaps.eosdis.nasa.gov/search/order/4/VNP46A2--5000/2022-01-01..2022-01-01/N/-159.9,22.4,-154.4,18.8
# files are VNP46A2.A2022001.h02v07.001.2022009102111.h5 and 
# VNP46A2.A2022001.h02v06.001.2022009101742.h5
# read two hc tile files for day 1 of 2022
temp_files<-list.files(pattern="VNP46A2.A2022001")

# read each hc files with rast
temp_files_rast <- sprc(lapply(temp_files, rast))

# merge raster files
data_raster <- mosaic(temp_files_rast)

# we need `DNB_BRDF-Corrected_NTL` layer only
data_raster_req <- data_raster$`DNB_BRDF-Corrected_NTL`

# assign crf since no crf is provided
crs(data_raster_req) <- "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0" 

# we need to get the nightlight data for zipcode level, so get the shape file to overlay on raster file
# https://files.hawaii.gov/dbedt/op/gis/data/zcta20.shp.zip

haw_sf<-read_sf("zcta20.shp") 

# convert shape file to spatial class object
haw_sp<-as(haw_sf,"Spatial") # gives spatial class object

# to make sure shape file overlays with raster
haw_sp<-sp::spTransform(haw_sp,crs(data_raster_req))

# convert sp to sf
haw_sf<-as(haw_sp,"sf")

# next crop raster file for area of my interest
data_raster_crop <- crop(data_raster_req, haw_sp)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you read the HDF files, you aren't getting any coordinates for latitude and longitude, and there are warning messages telling you this which you seem to have ignored:

```
temp_files_rast <- sprc(lapply(temp_files, rast))
Warning messages:
1: [rast] unknown extent
 
2: [rast] unknown extent
```

If you load one raster you can see a bit more:

```
> r1 = rast("./VNP46A2.A2022001.h02v06.001.2022009101742.h5")
Warning message:
[rast] unknown extent
 
> r1
class       : SpatRaster 
dimensions  : 2400, 2400, 7  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
resolution  : 1, 1  (x, y)
extent      : 0, 2400, 0, 2400  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
```

So the rasters are given an extent in pixels (these are 2400x2400 pixel rasters).

When you then assign it a lat-long CRS (not "crf") you are saying this raster covers the area from 0 latitude to 2400 latitude, which is meaningless.

From then on it all goes wrong. You really need to know the correct extent in lat-long of the HDF files, and I don't see this in the HDF metadata.

If you do assume the HDF and the shapefile represent the same extent you can set them to have the same extent and CRS:

```
ext(data_raster_req) = ext(haw_sf)
crs(data_raster_req) = crs(haw_sf)
```

which produces this when mapped:

```
> plot(data_raster_req)
> plot(st_geometry(haw_sf),add=TRUE)
```

[image]

which might be right - I don't know. But that's how you do it.

But essentially, you need the extent of the HDF files.

Answer (score 2):

As @Spacedman has mentioned, your raster data is lacking a proper definition of the coordinate reference system and extent.

According to the [product information](https://ladsweb.modaps.eosdis.nasa.gov/missions-and-measurements/products/VNP46A2/#product-information) for VNP46A2, your product has a global coverage and the spatial resolution is specified with 15 arc-seconds. Data comes in tiles (here: h02v06 and h02v07), so all you need is to find the extent of the tiles used. I found a shapefile with tile geometries e.g. at [blackmarble.gsfc.nasa.gov](https://blackmarble.gsfc.nasa.gov/tools/BlackMarbleTiles.zip).

Making use of `{terra}`, these properties can be (extracted and) defined like this:

```r
library(terra)
#> terra 1.6.17

# read hdf5 file
r <- rast("VNP46A2.A2022001.h02v06.001.2022009101742.h5")
#> Warning: [rast] unknown extent
r
#> class       : SpatRaster 
#> dimensions  : 2400, 2400, 7  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
#> resolution  : 1, 1  (x, y)
#> extent      : 0, 2400, 0, 2400  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#> coord. ref. :  
#> sources     : VNP46A2.A2022001.h02v06.001.2022009101742.h5://DNB_BRDF-Corrected_NTL  
#>               VNP46A2.A2022001.h02v06.001.2022009101742.h5://DNB_Lunar_Irradiance  
#>               VNP46A2.A2022001.h02v06.001.2022009101742.h5://Gap_Filled_DNB_BRDF-Corrected_NTL  
#>               ... and 4 more source(s)
#> varnames    : DNB_BRDF-Corrected_NTL 
#>               DNB_Lunar_Irradiance 
#>               Gap_Filled_DNB_BRDF-Corrected_NTL 
#>               ...
#> names       : DNB_B~d_NTL, DNB_L~iance, Gap_F~d_NTL, Lates~ieval, Manda~_Flag, QF_Cl~_Mask, ... 
#> min values  :           1,          ? ,          ? ,          ? ,          ? ,          ? , ... 
#> max values  :       65535,          ? ,          ? ,          ? ,          ? ,          ? , ...

# read tile grid
tiles <- vect("BlackMarbleTiles.shp")

# get relevant index
ind <- tiles[["TileID"]] == "h02v06"

# subset grid to one tile, get extent
e <- tiles[ind] |> ext()

# adjust crs and extent of the tile in use
crs(r) <- "epsg:4326"
ext(r) <- e

# subset data to relevant layer and inspect
r[["DNB_BRDF-Corrected_NTL"]]
#> class       : SpatRaster 
#> dimensions  : 2400, 2400, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
#> resolution  : 0.004166667, 0.004166667  (x, y)
#> extent      : -160, -150, 20.00012, 30.00012  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#> coord. ref. : lon/lat WGS 84 (EPSG:4326) 
#> source      : VNP46A2.A2022001.h02v06.001.2022009101742.h5://DNB_BRDF-Corrected_NTL 
#> varname     : DNB_BRDF-Corrected_NTL 
#> name        : DNB_BRDF-Corrected_NTL 
#> min value   :                      1 
#> max value   :                  65535

# resolution equal to 15 arc-seconds?
res(r)[1] == 1 / 3600 * 15
#> [1] TRUE
```